# Python/Tkinter: reading inputs from a subwindow

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm preparing a GUI application with Python and Tkinter (I'm a newbie with this language).

I have a main window and a config sub-window with some text parameters that I open with:

```
def config_open():
  global wdw, e
  wdw = Toplevel()
  wdw.geometry('+400+400')

  w = Label(wdw, text="Parameter 1", justify=RIGHT)
  w.grid(row=1, column=0)
  e = Entry(wdw)
  e.grid(row=1, column=1)
  e.focus_set()
```

Then I add an "OK" button that calls:

```
def config_save():
  global wdw, e
  user_input = e.get().strip()
  print user_input
```

It works, but I'm declaring everything as global. Is there a better way to refer to elements inside a subwindow?

Comment: Where is `ok` button? in main window or in config window?

Comment: It's may be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718073/how-to-create-child-window-and-communicate-with-parent-in-tkinter

Comment: The OK button is inside the config window.

Answer (score 1):

```
from Tkinter import *

def config_open():
    wdw = Toplevel()
    wdw.geometry('+400+400')
    # Makes window modal
    wdw.grab_set()

    # Variable to store entry value
    user_input = StringVar()
    Label(wdw, text="Parameter 1", justify=RIGHT).grid(row=1, column=0)
    e = Entry(wdw, textvariable=user_input)
    e.grid(row=1, column=1)
    e.focus_set()
    Button(wdw, text='Ok', command=wdw.destroy).grid(row=2, column=1)
    # Show the window and wait for it to close
    wdw.wait_window(wdw)
    # Window has been closed
    data = {'user_input': user_input.get().strip(),
            'another-option': 'value of another-option'}
    return data

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry('+200+200')
        self.label_var = StringVar()
        self.user_input = None
        Button(self.root, text='Configure', command=self.get_options).place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
        Label(self.root, textvariable=self.label_var).place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, anchor=CENTER)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def get_options(self):
        options = config_open()
        self.user_input = options['user_input']
        self.label_var.set(self.user_input)

App()
```